# Handling Space in Filename for sed command

Tags: linux, centos, sed, command-line, grep

I have 3 files: `en.json`, `en 1.json` and `en 2.json`. All of them have the below content

```
    {
      "ABC" : "/long_name",
      "DFG" : "/{long_name}"
    }
```

I run below command to replace `ABC` with `123` and `DFG` with `456`

```
grep -El 'ABC|DFG' *.json | xargs  sed -ibak -e 's#ABC#123#g' -e 's#DFG#456#g'
```

text gets replaced in `en.json` but for `en 1.json` and `en 2.json` it fails with the below error

```
sed: en: No such file or directory
```

For some reason, the space is ignored and I am not sure how I can handle it within the command

Comment: Try running `grep` with `-Z/--null` to use a null byte as delimiter, and pass `-0/--null` to `xargs` aswell

Comment: not sure i understood it

Comment: @AdityaNaik, Panki was suggesting `grep -Z -El 'ABC|DFG' *.json | xargs -0 sed -ibak -e 's#ABC#123#g' -e 's#DFG#456#g'`.  In other words, add `-Z` to the options you're using with `grep`, and add `-0` as an option to `xargs`.

Comment: Tried it but I get below sed: en 3.json en.json en 2.json : No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

The problem you're seeing is that the space is being treated as a separator.

A simple example:

```
% echo a b | xargs ls
ls: cannot access a: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access b: No such file or directory
```

We can see `ls` tried to look for files `a` and `b`.

Instead we should tell `xargs` and `grep` to use a different separator; the best one is the NUL characater (\0).  To do this you can use `-Z` with `grep` and `-0` with `xargs`.

So your command becomes

```
grep -Z .... | xargs -0 ....
```

For example:

```
$ ls
en 1.json  en 2.json  en.json
$ grep -Z -El ABC *.json | xargs -0 sed -ibak -e 's/ABC/HHH/'
$ ls
en 1.json  en 1.jsonbak  en 2.json  en 2.jsonbak  en.json  en.jsonbak
```

We can see the 3 files got modified ("bak" files created).

Comment: I tried it however now th issue is sed command is trreating all files as one and i get below error

sed: en 3.json
en.json
en 2.json : No such file or directory

Comment: Then you possibly made a typo;  I just ran an example (answer updated with the example).on my CentOS machine.  You need both the `grep -Z` and `xargs -0` for this to work.

Answer (score 0):

If in doubt use a loop:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

while IFS= read -r file; do
    sed -ibak -e 's#ABC#123#g' -e 's#DFG#456#g' "$file"
done < <(grep -El 'ABC|DFG' *.json)
```

The above assumes your file names do not contain newlines.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a JSON-aware tool such as `jq` to perform the replacements:

```
jq '."123" = ."ABC" | ."456" = ."DFG" | del(."ABC", ."DFG")'
```

Output

```
{
  "123": "/long_name",
  "456": "/{long_name}"
}
```

Applying this to all three files, and remembering to quote the filenames that contain spaces,

```
for file in en.json 'en 1.json' 'en 2.json'
do
    cp -p -- "$file" "$file.old"
    jq '."123" = ."ABC" | ."456" = ."DFG" | del(."ABC", ."DFG")'<"$file.old" >"$file" &&
        : rm -f -- "$file.old"
done
```

Remove the `:` from in front of `rm` to remove the saved original file(s).